# Pass firebase auth credentials from ionic app to external website

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an ionic app using firebase auth. In one page, I have in-app-browser to open a website which allows the user to save some items to their collection. How can I pass along the auth info to this external website, so the user doesn't need to log in again? (i.e. how the external website knows it's the same user who has already login within the ionic app)

Comment: It is not clear why you can't add the items in the ionic app directly. If you insist on opening the browser to run some authenticated request and you actually own and trust that page, you can pass the Firebase ID token to the browser in the URL and then run the operation with that authenticated operation using the ID token.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was trying to build a page which integrates fabric.js library, and there are hiccups when it was used with angular, so I tried to have a plain javascript page (no angular), and redirects the user to that page. 
Since the user needs to login to save/retrieve data from the firebase database, so I need to pass the auth. What I did was force the user to login once they redirect to the plain js page, which seems redundant as the user was already logged in the ionic app, so I was thinking if I can simply pass the auth token and make the flow a bit smooth.